# Knocking sound coming from Torque Converter in my two speed

Tags: chevrolet, automatic-transmission, torque-converter, belair

I daily my 63 Chevy Belair Wagon. Transmission is the original GM Two-speed Powerglide with (I believe) the original (13?)-inch torque converter.

Here are my issues:

- Car lurches hard and knocks when put in gear.
- Reluctant to shift out of first until it has been driven a few miles.
- While coming to a stop, loud knock on downshift.
- There is also a strong oscillating vibration that begins around 45 mph and only increases in frequency with the position of the throttle.

Note: the vibration does not change linearly to the RPM or velocity of the car, ONLY the position of the gas pedal/throttle (i.e. with the gas pedal depressed slightly the vibration goes: "vrumm... vrumm..." With the gas pedal depressed further the vibration increases in rate: "vrum.. vrum.. vrum.. vrum").

I'm hoping this is just an issue with the torque converter but any insights will help.

Comment: Does it do this when the car is in park/neutral? If it does, find the throttle kick down linkage. It should be attached at the carb throttle area and will run down to the tranny. Pull on this (force it to engage) without moving the throttle (no engine difference through carburetor). You may need to disconnect it from the carb to do this. See if it does the same thing without changing how the engine is running.